# Display integer value on TextView

Tags: android, eclipse, button, textview

For some reason the value of my int does not show up on the TextView
Button works properly, but shows 0

Code:

```
btn5.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int vot=(r2/(r1+r2))*vol;
        txt4.setText(String.valueOf(vot));
    };
});}
```

Comment: try this `txt4.setText(" "+vot);`

Comment: what are the value of r1 and r2

Comment: what is the value of `vot`

Comment: and also what is the value of vol i think may be its getting 0 with int

Comment: use DOUBLE instead of int and try again

Comment: @Bhanu vol=12  so it's not 0

Comment: @GrIsHu String.valueOf() also covert int to string

Comment: Just print **vot** in log and check that what value did you get?

Comment: @BhanuSharma Yes it do. But as it seems your value is in double. So its better to cast directly.

Comment: @GrIsHu didn't get u directly means what ??

Comment: @BhanuSharma Sometimes it fails to parse the value using valueOf method. Just try out with my answer.

Comment: Show r1 and r2 variable and vol variable value.

Comment: @GrIsHu its also getting 0 from ur ans hahaha may be i think it maths prob dude

Comment: @BhanuSharma Then there must be issue in your calculation. Check out all the values of `r1,r2,vol` by printing and also print the result `vot`.

Comment: int vot=(1280/(1280+1280))*12;
        System.out.println("and the maths value is == " + vot+"");
i use this

Answer (score 0):

```
btn_save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                double r2 = 10.0;
                double r1= 20.0;
                double vol = 30.0;

                double vot=(r2/(r1+r2))*vol;
                txtvew1.setText(Double.toString(vol));

            }
        });
```

Comment: values are set outside of the button

Answer (score 0):

```
int vot=(r2/(r1+r2))*vol;
```

Based on the comments, `r1` and `r2` are `1280` and `vol` is `12`. Let's see how it goes in integer math:

```
  (1280/(1280+1280))*12
= (1280/2560)*12
= 0*12
= 0
```

Now, let's change one of the operands to `double` to make it floating point math:

```
  (1280.0/(1280+1280))*12
= (1280.0/2560)*12
= 0.5*12
= 6.0
```

Or switch the order and keep the integer math:

```
  12*1280/(1280+1280)
= 15360/2560
= 6
```

So, probably the easiest is to change the `vot` calculation like this:

```
int vot=vol*r2/(r1+r2);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
xt4.setText(String.valueOf(vot)+"");
```

Answer (score -1):

xt4.setText(vot+"");

here is the code.